# Upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04 wants to remove MariaDB Server

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, mariadb

I have a VPS with Ubuntu 16.04 that I use as webserver and Nextcloud Server.
I want to upgrade my VPS to Ubuntu 18.04.
As I do

```
do-release-upgrade
```

It tells me that if I agree to proceed it would remove completely MariaDB (both server and client). The output looks like this:

No longer supported: cpp-5 fonts-nanum gcc-5-base gcc-6-base
  gucharmap libasan2 libgcc-5-dev libgtk2-perl libstdc++-5-dev ntp
  openjdk-8-jre subversion wvdial

```
Remove: mariadb-server-10.0 mytop php7.0-curl
  python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat

Remove (was auto installed) adwaita-icon-theme-full
  gnome-themes-standard-data libcurl3 libdfu1 libdouble-conversion1v5
  libgsl2 libguvcview-1.1-1 libjpeg-progs libmagickcore-6.q16-2
  libmagickcore-6.q16-2-extra libmagickwand-6.q16-2 libmailutils4
  libnss3-nssdb libobrender32 libobt2 libperl5.22 libsane
  mariadb-client-10.0 mariadb-client-core-10.0
  mariadb-server-core-10.0 mplayer2 perl-modules-5.22
  pulseaudio-module-x11 unity-control-center-faces
  xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse
```

Also, in the `Upgrade` section, I can see

```
mariadb-common mariadb-server
```

These are the packages of MariaDB I've installed:

```
root@vmi117654:~# dpkg -l mariadb*
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                          Version             Architecture        Description
+++-=============================-===================-===================-===============================================================
ii  mariadb-client-10.0           10.0.38-0ubuntu0.16 amd64               MariaDB database client binaries
un  mariadb-client-5.5            <none>              <none>              (no description available)
ii  mariadb-client-core-10.0      10.0.38-0ubuntu0.16 amd64               MariaDB database core client binaries
un  mariadb-client-core-5.5       <none>              <none>              (no description available)
ii  mariadb-common                10.0.38-0ubuntu0.16 all                 MariaDB common metapackage
un  mariadb-galera-server         <none>              <none>              (no description available)
un  mariadb-galera-server-5.5     <none>              <none>              (no description available)
ii  mariadb-server                10.0.38-0ubuntu0.16 all                 MariaDB database server (metapackage depending on the latest ve
ii  mariadb-server-10.0           10.0.38-0ubuntu0.16 amd64               MariaDB database server binaries
un  mariadb-server-5.5            <none>              <none>              (no description available)
ii  mariadb-server-core-10.0      10.0.38-0ubuntu0.16 amd64               MariaDB database core server files
un  mariadb-server-core-5.5       <none>              <none>              (no description available)
un  mariadb-test                  <none>              <none>              (no description available)
un  mariadb-tokudb-engine-10.0    <none>              <none>              (no description available)
un  mariadb-tokudb-engine-5.5     <none>              <none>              (no description available)
```

How can I upgrade Ubuntu while keeping installed MariaDB?

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not getting rid of MariaDB entirely. It's merely upgrading from 10.0 to 10.1. Part of upgrading means removing the older 10.0 packages.

Let it continue.

If it were *really* getting rid of MariaDB, you would see the packages `mariadb-server` and `mariadb-client` (without version numbers) among the list of packages to be deleted.

Another clue is the phrase `(was auto installed)` in the output. That means these are not packages that you --the human-- specified. Instead, these are mere dependencies of something else that you specified...like `mariadb-server` and `mariadb-client`